# building layers with geodjango and google maps by social network users

Tags: django, google-maps

I would like to build the following but do not know if this is feasible:
- within a proprietary social network running on django users can lookup via the satellite view (and/or streetview) certain 'items' (e.g. their own car parked in their own street -if it was there of course while they were shooting...-), then mark it.
- after marking other members can see the mark on google maps (with or without satellite view).

The 'items' are not necessarily on a street/ do not have an 'address', so could be in the desert/ middle of nowhere. As far as I know it is possible to build layers, mark with coordinates and store these in a database, so my feasability questions boils down to:
1) can you mark from the Google maps sattelite view? and from streetview?
2) after building such a layer can you share it with other users WITHOUT them having google accounts?
3) any tips on how to go about? use geodjango?

Comment: Just to be sure. Do you want those marks to be displayed on GoogleMaps or just use googlemaps has a baselayer for your app?

Comment: I am not sure I know the exact difference... I suppose GoogleMaps would be available to all googlemaps users (so basically everybody on the internet). My markers on googlemaps would only need to be seen by Members of the proprietary social network, so I suppose a baselayer would be fine then...?! Actually when a user marks a spot he becomes a 'member of this marker' and other users can then also become members of this 'marker group'. So that's an additional requirement...

Comment: Mmh, I added 'WITHOUT' in the original question; should have been there from the start...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So yes Googlemaps as a baselayer is enough. You just need to use the [API](https://developers.google.com/maps/?hl=FR). I found a similar question to yours [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/568151/django-google-maps-integration?rq=1), it might help you.

To answer you question completly:

1) Yes satellite view will work. Not sure how to handle it with street view. Not sure it is part of the API either.

2) Yes no worry. Your app, your users.

3) Geodjango is a really good framework, but it server side language. The major part of the work will be map functionnalities in JS. So you want to dig for THE good map API (OpenLayers, Leaflet, Google...) before worrying about Geodjango.

Cheers.