# Google map in Django

Tags: django, google-maps

I am trying to implement Google maps onto my Django site, but i have no idea how. Can anyone direct me to the right resources or teach me how? I am also new to Django, but I already have experience with models and views, but please explain me to in simple terms.

Comment: possible duplicate of [django, google maps integration](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/568151/django-google-maps-integration)

Answer (score 3):

you  can start with this:
(customize map with google api [MarkerOptions](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?csw=1#MarkerOptions) ,[MapOption](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?csw=1#MapOptions))

```
<html >
<body onLoad="initialize()">
                  <div class="col-sm-offset-1" id="map_canvas" style="width:500; height:500"></div>
                  <br>
                  <input type="text" id="lat">
                  <input type="text" id="lng">            
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<style>
  body{
    text-align:center;
  }
  .gmap3{
    margin: 20px auto;
    border: 1px dashed #C0C0C0;
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
  }
</style>    
<script type="text/javascript">
   var map;
 function initialize() {
 var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(36.85341604753753,10.176080866332995);
 var myOptions = {
 zoom: 14,
 minZoom:14,
 center: myLatlng,
 draggable:false,
 mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE
 }
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions); 
 var marker = new google.maps.Marker({


draggable: true,
position: myLatlng, 
map: map,
  });
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function (event) {
document.getElementById("lat").value = this.getPosition().lat();
document.getElementById("lng").value = this.getPosition().lng();
}
); 
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is this javascript?  How can you use python/django with this?

Answer (score 2):

how about this 2 django packages (easy to use with good documentation ):

- [django-easy-maps](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-easy-maps)
- [django-geoposition](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-geoposition)

Comment: Do I need to have those packages to implement google maps?

Comment: no if you want just use google map api directly in your site